# Im trying to add an attempt counter in my guessing word game and when i run my program the attempt is not increasing and in messagebox it remains 0

Tags: c#

can you guys help im trying to add an attempt counter and when im running my program the attempt is not increasing both in the windows form and in messagebox, heres my code below  can you guys help me

```
attempt = 0;
{
if combobox1.Text == handler)
{
MessageBox.Show("Correct!" + You guessed it in " attempt + "Attempt/s");
attempt++;

this.close
}
else
{
MessageBox.Show("Incorret Try Again!");
attempt++;
}
Label1.Text = Attempts: " + attempt;
```

Comment: There are some syntax errors in your code. Try fixing these first. E. g. no opening bracket after the `if`, uneven number of quotes inside `MessageBox.Show`...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
attempt = 0;
if (combobox1.Text == handler)
{
    MessageBox.Show($"Correct! You guessed it in {attempt} Attempt/s");
    attempt++;
    this.Close();
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Try Again!");
    attempt++;
}
Label1.Text = $"Attempts: {attempt}";
```